# Tab tag material ui

Tags: material-ui

can't use link tag inside material tab tag in material ui
none of codes inside Tab doesn't work

```
<Tabs>
             <Tab>
                 <Link
                     style={isActive(history, "/cart")}
                     to="/cart"
                >
                     Cart{" "}
                     <sup>
                         <small className="cart-badge">{itemTotal()}</small>
                     </sup>
                </Link>
             <Tab/>
<Tabs/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the documentation `Tab` doesn't support `children`. Instead you can use `component` prop.

https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#props

```
<Tabs>
   <Tab
      component={() => (
          <Link
             style={isActive(history, "/cart")}
             to="/cart"
             >
              Cart{" "}
              <sup>
                <small className="cart-badge">{itemTotal()}</small>
              </sup>
          </Link>
     )}/>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: you're awesome man, thanks for reply, have nice coding

Comment: @arminsali If you feel my answer helped you, please accept this as correct answer. Happy coding!! :)